# Pass all values from second table in inner join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have multiple inner joins on one table and I want to pass all values from second table column in where clause.

e.g.

```
select * from Table A 
inner join Table B on A.id = B.id 
inner join Table C on A.id = C.id  
Where C.somevalue = (all values from this column)
```

How can I achieve this behavior in `where` clause.

Comment: What are you having right side of this where filter `C.somevalue = (all values from this column)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `IN` clause in conjuction with the `WHERE` to make something like this:

`WHERE C.somevalue IN (SELECT col FROM table)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`

```
select * 
from Table A 
inner join Table B on A.id = B.id 
inner join Table C on A.id = C.id  
Where C.somevalue IN (SELECT your_column FROM your_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is coming from Table B you can keep your condition in the join clause

```
select * 
from Table A 
inner join Table B on A.id = B.id 
inner join Table C on A.id = C.id  
                  and C.somevalue = B.column_you_prefer
```